# AttributeError: module 'resnet' has no attribute 'ResnetBuilder'

Tags: python, keras, attributeerror, resnet

Hi I tried to run following program and surprisingly I get below error:

```
AttributeError: module 'resnet' has no attribute 'ResnetBuilder'
```

during running ResNet from [GitHub](https://github.com/raghakot/keras-resnet/blob/master/resnet.py) but I don't undestand why it happens in following part:

```py
 model = resnet.ResnetBuilder.build_resnet_18((img_channels, img_rows, img_cols), nb_classes)
 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                 optimizer='adam',
```

considering `ResnetBuilder` it already defined here:

```py
class ResnetBuilder(object):
    @staticmethod
    def build(input_shape, num_outputs, block_fn, repetitions):
        """Builds a custom ResNet like architecture.
        Args:
            input_shape: The input shape in the form (nb_channels, nb_rows, nb_cols)
            num_outputs: The number of outputs at final softmax layer
            block_fn: The block function to use. This is either `basic_block` or `bottleneck`.
                The original paper used basic_block for layers < 50
            repetitions: Number of repetitions of various block units.
                At each block unit, the number of filters are doubled and the input size is halved
        Returns:
            The keras `Model`.
        """
        _handle_dim_ordering()
        if len(input_shape) != 3:
            raise Exception("Input shape should be a tuple (nb_channels, nb_rows, nb_cols)")

        # Permute dimension order if necessary
        if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'tf':
            input_shape = (input_shape[1], input_shape[2], input_shape[0])

        # Load function from str if needed.
        block_fn = _get_block(block_fn)

        input = Input(shape=input_shape)
        conv1 = _conv_bn_relu(filters=64, kernel_size=(7, 7), strides=(2, 2))(input)
        pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(conv1)

        block = pool1
        filters = 64
        for i, r in enumerate(repetitions):
            block = _residual_block(block_fn, filters=filters, repetitions=r, is_first_layer=(i == 0))(block)
            filters *= 2

        # Last activation
        block = _bn_relu(block)

        # Classifier block
        block_shape = K.int_shape(block)
        pool2 = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(block_shape[ROW_AXIS], block_shape[COL_AXIS]),
                                 strides=(1, 1))(block)
        flatten1 = Flatten()(pool2)
        dense = Dense(units=num_outputs, kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                      activation="softmax")(flatten1)

        model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=dense)
        return model

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_18(input_shape, num_outputs):
        return ResnetBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, basic_block, [2, 2, 2, 2])

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_34(input_shape, num_outputs):
        return ResnetBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, basic_block, [3, 4, 6, 3])

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_50(input_shape, num_outputs):
        return ResnetBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, bottleneck, [3, 4, 6, 3])

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_101(input_shape, num_outputs):
        return ResnetBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, bottleneck, [3, 4, 23, 3])

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_152(input_shape, num_outputs):
        return ResnetBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, bottleneck, [3, 8, 36, 3])
```

Any ideas, how it could be fixed?

Comment: Did you import `resnet`? Try `from resnet import ResnetBuilder`. It's always worked for me...

Comment: Do you have a module of your own named `resnet`?

Comment: @Engineero Unfortunately that doesn't work and returns this : `ImportError: cannot import name 'ResnetBuilder' from 'resnet' (/home/user/anaconda3/envs/HW/lib/python3.7/site-packages/resnet/__init__.py)`

Comment: Wait, resnet isn't pip-installable, so what is this resnet that's hanging out in your site-packages directory? You should probably have a copy of the `resnet.py` file in your working directory or on your python path somewhere, and that's the resnet you need to import from.

Comment: @Engineero Oh, that's why! I installed it by `pip install resnet` I thought by that it will be transferred in right path :D So How can I correctly save `resnet.py` in python path via terminal/Jupyter Notebook from GitHub if it's not the case?

Comment: @PeterWood it seems so but what I have done is I copied `cifar10.py` and `resnet.py` in individual cells in the jupyter notebook and run the code and I installed `resnet` by `pip install resnet`. Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try another package:

Try this [repo](https://github.com/qubvel/classification_models)

```
!pip install image-classifiers

from classification_models import Classifiers
classifier, preprocess_input = Classifiers.get('resnet18')
model = classifier((224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet')
```